# Proving a multivariable function is not differentiable and existence of partial derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

So i have to prove that this functions is not differentiable at $(0,0)$:

$f(x)= \left\lvert x \right\rvert+\left\lvert y \right\rvert$

Seems pretty obvious, but i don't know how to do it formally, i can prove that the partial derivatives don't exist (i obtain different numbers if a aproach from ($h->0+$) or ($h->0-$)) but i don't know if that is enough to show that the function is not differentiable.

i can decompose the function in 4

$  f(x) =
\begin{cases}
x+y,  & \text{if $x$ > 0 & $y$ > 0} \\\
x-y, & \text{if $x$ > 0 & $y$ < 0} \\\
-x+y, & \text{if $x$ < 0 & $y$ > 0} \\\
-x-y, & \text{if $x$ < 0 & $y$ < 0}
\end{cases}$

but then i don't know exactly what to do. Show that the function has different tangent planes in each quadrant? Is that enough?

My final question is "Is there a function that is differentiable at a point but it doesn't have partial derivatives at that point?"

Comment: "i can prove that the partial derivatives don't exist" Then you're done. Boom!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a function is differentiable at a point, then all partial derivatives exist at that point. What fails is the converse: the existence of the partial derivatives is not enough to imply differentiability (continuity of the partial derivatives is).

Comment: Thanks, i think i got confused thinking that "partial derivatives does not imply differentiability" meant that "not partial derivatives does not imply not differentiability" Thanks for the clear up.